# How to add simple image upload to a form?

Tags: php, image, forms, file-upload, asyncfileupload

I have a html form. I want to add a simple image upload feature to it and it will be send the image to a php page called "next.php". Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: A Google search for PHP upload file returns about 25 million results, such as: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp
PS: I see you tagged your question `asyncfileupload`: do you want the upload to be asynchronous?

Answer (score 3):

Create an HTML form like the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="next.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="image">Image:</label>
<input type="image" name="image" id="image" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your "next.php" file could handle the image similar to this:

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br />";
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

At this point, you can make it more secure by checking the type and ensuring it's only jpg, gif, png, or of the sort. I would recommend copying the image into 2 or 3 sizes (thumb, medium, original), and deleting it from the temporary directory. You could use [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to resize the images and then use the [filesystem](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) functions to move around and delete temporary uploads.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any means to interact with a file `input` on the client-side, so you'll need to verify/validate the uploaded file server-side (within the 'next.php' script), but this should be enough:

```
<form action="path/to/next.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The enctype attribute has to be set or this won't work.  He'll be beating his head against the wall trying to figure out what is going wrong...

Comment: @Brian H, oops...thanks, and edited. There's always **something**... =D